# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webHandler' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

Adding open API to the Spring cloud gateway project cause the error as

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/WebFluxAutoConfiguration$EnableWebFluxConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/WebFluxAutoConfiguration$EnableWebFluxConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerWelcome] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3d4eac69]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:62) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at fete.bird.fetebirdapigateway.FeteBirdApiGatewayApplication.main(FeteBirdApiGatewayApplication.java:13) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/WebFluxAutoConfiguration$EnableWebFluxConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerWelcome] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3d4eac69]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:621) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1251) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:378) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.initStrategies(DispatcherHandler.java:116) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.setApplicationContext(DispatcherHandler.java:111) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:100) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerWelcome] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3d4eac69]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector.selectMethods(MethodIntrospector.java:72) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:206) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:189) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:157) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:126) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3244) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2387) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

**Gradle Dependency**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.4.3' --> Adding this causing the issue
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the issue

Spring Gateway is depend on webflux, so need to add below dependency

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.4.3'
```